# How to reset RAS Entry status in Windows CE 5?

Tags: c#, windows-ce, vpn, ras, l2tp

I'm developing a Windows CE application which is a Network Connector using C#, .NET Compact Framework 3.5. Installed OS is Windows CE 5.

The app is for 3G Network and VPN Connection. It makes the device on 3g network after then VPN.

The problem is when 3G Network is disconnected, the app is able to reconnect on it. But VPN isn't. When the app try to reconnect VPN, just being raised disconnected event without any network request. Also It doesn't work with RAS Entry icon where Start->setting->Network Connection window in OS.

I want to reset RAS Entry status to be able to reconnect normally.

Do you have any ideas?